# does length of name or id value matters in performance in javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance

is lenghth of name/id value affect the performance? 
for example; 
performance wise which option is better ?

```
<input type='text' name='candidatefirstname' id='candidatefirstnameID' />
```

or

```
 <input type='text' name='fname' id='fnameId' />
```

Comment: Don't know about performance, but that'll increase the file size

Comment: once parsed, the two copies execute at the exact same speed.

Comment: i have html page with container div ,Container divs has two divs 1)main  type and  2) subtype  , when page loads  maintype div is visible .when user clicks on next button maintype div hides and subtype div gets visible but after click on next button it takes some noticeable time to show other div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the previous poster states, it's minimal. Might matter slightly if the script is large and especially if it's not cached and used frequently, in that case use a minimizer.

Answer (score 0):

Modern computers are so fast that the difference is not significant.

Answer (score 0):

Since Javascript is a runtime interpreted language (or formally known as Scripting Language), the variable name length does not make a difference.

However, you might want to consider that on a larger scale of many identifiers with long names, the size of the HTML that the client will  have to download is increased and that will increase loading time for the user.

Comment: then the length of the ID won't really make a difference as long as these are reasonable - technically it is possible to have an ID as long as the maximum string length in which case even 1 ID would affect performance - though I'm sure this wasn't what you had in mind :)